# C++ overloading; variable args of same type?

Tags: c++, overloading, default-value, optional-parameters

I have a class, whose constructor looks like this:

```
Chunker::Chunker(int chunkSizeX, int chunkSizeY){
    chunkX = chunkSizeX;
    chunkY = chunkSizeY;
}
```

I would like to offer the user the ability to have either `chunkSizeY` or `chunkSizeX` to have a default value (which needs to be calculated by `Chunker`).

I.E so they might pass in a 'AUTO' keyword or something so that the constructor knows.

Can I do something like:

```
Chunker::Chunker(int chunkSizeX, char chunkSizeY)

Chunker::Chunker(char chunkSizeX, int chunkSizeY)

Chunker::Chunker(char chunkSizeX, char chunkSizeY)
```

So that if it gets a `char` for one or both of the values, it knows to auto-calculate them?

I'm sure their must be a better/standard way I don't know of yet....?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, no, there is no better way that I know of. What are you asking?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the way you describe?

Comment: I have no problem with it if that is the 'normal' way. I am a relative newbie to c++ and it 'felt' like I wan't doing it in the 'standard' method or perhaps there is a more succinct way?

Comment: Is casting to `int` from `char` a bad plan here?

Comment: Where is there any casting, @tadman? That said, casting is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Beta No better way? This approach is not very expressive at all and would certainly confuse me. I'd recommend using `boost::optional`, or alternatively the builder pattern as Paul Evans has described. Another common way to do this is using pointers, where a null pointer represents an omitted argument, but I find that is also not expressive.

Answer (score 5):

You may use a special empty class to help:

```
struct Default {};

class Chunker
{
public:
    Chunker(int x, int y) : chunkX(x), chunkY(y) {}
    Chunker(Default, int y) : chunkX(42), chunkY(y) {}
    Chunker(int x, int Default) : chunkX(x), chunkY(42) {}

private:
    int chunkX;
    int chunkY;
};
```

usage:

```
Chunker c(1, 2);
Chunker cx(3, Default{});
Chunker cy(Default{}, 4);
```

or use "static builder"

```
class Chunker
{
public:
    Chunker(int x, int y) : chunkX(x), chunkY(y) {}
    static Chunker FromX(int x) { return Chunker(x, 42); }
    static Chunker FromY(int y) { return Chunker(42, y); }
private:
    int chunkX;
    int chunkY;
};
```

usage:

```
Chunker c(1, 2);
Chunker cx = Chunker::FromX(3);
Chunker cy = Chunker::FromY(4);
```

Comment: Nice examples, thanks. Quite like the use of static functions.

Answer (score 4):

Simply write a helper class that builtds `Chunker`s,  something like:

```
class MakeChunker {

    void setX(int x) { ...
    void setY(int y) { ...
    Chunker make()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest Boost.Optional, which will give you code like this:

```
void function(optional<int> x, optional<int> y) {
    if (x) {
        // use *x
    }
    if (y) {
        // use *y
    }
}
```

That said, for the case of constructors, it's sometimes a good idea to add a static factory function in the class:

```
class Chunker {
    static Chunker create_with_x(int x) {
        ...
    }
    static Chunker create_with_y(int y) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple constructors in C++ as long as they have different signatures, and the appropriate constructor will be selected by the compiler for each call.

So you can perfectly do :

In *Chunker.cpp*

```
Chunker::Chunker(int chunkSizeX, char chunkSizeY) {...} // First constructor
Chunker::Chunker(char chunkSizeX, int chunkSizeY) {...} // Second constructor
Chunker::Chunker(char chunkSizeX, char chunkSizeY) {...} // Third constructor
```

Then in another file of your program:

```
Chunker::chunker chunker1 = Chunker::Chunker(1, 'b') // First constructor is used
Chunker::chunker chunker2 = Chunker::Chunker('a', 2) // Second constructor is used
Chunker::chunker chunker3 = Chunker::Chunker('a', 'b') // Third constructor is used
```

Comment: `char` != `const char*`

Comment: You probably mean `'b'`, not `"b"`; dtto for other cases.

Comment: The `char` parameters should not be `'a'` or `'b'` or anything. OP wanted "AUTO keyword or something". Using explicit and different `char`s is confusing. Also you should mention implicit conversions (e.g. what happens when the constructor's parameters are `size_t` and `char`?)